# Deploy Apache Spark on Heroku

Tags: heroku, apache-spark

I am looking for a way to deploy apache spark on Heroku. My use case is I am having a cluster on Heroku which runs apache spark. There is a webservice which is running and interacting with the service. The service is getting data from the hdfs system.

Any suggestion if this can be feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to run Apache Spark on Heroku. Heroku is a Platform as a Service. You will need Infrastructure as a Service (e.g. Digital Ocean) to create a Apache Spark cluster. Alternatively, you can use Databricks.

Comment: With the release of Heroku private spaces and dyno dns it is now possible to deploy Apache Spark cluster on Heroku.  Please checkout following button that deploys a Spark cluster on Heroku. https://github.com/heroku/spark-in-space